# Savepoint using Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, savepoints

The issue is i m using save or update in hibernate on temporary base...

now when i finally fire update it will store it in DB permanently otherwise rollback it..

how to make save point using hibernate base is spring.

like

```
HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplateObj = getHibernateTemplate();

hibernateTemplateObj.saveOrUpdateAll(userList);
```

now i would like to add savepoint in connection before save or update.

Any help would be appriciate..

Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code

```
hibernateConection.setAutocommit(false);

Savepoint savepoint = hibernateConection.setSavepoint();
```

where, `hibernateConection` is object of third party library `liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.HibernateConnection`